# How to stop URL loading in InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic3, inappbrowser

I currently have an Ionic app that uses the InAppBrowser plugin to display a website. On the website are links to social media (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram).

I have currently coded it so when a social media link is clicked it opens the URL inside the devices default browser or in the official app if installed.

My problem is "When it opens the social media URL inside the default browser or the official app, it still also loads the URL inside the InAppBrowser."

Is there anyway I can cancel it loading the URL inside the InAppBrowser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  tag with blank target.

Ex. `<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I create the InAppBrowser with the _blank target already.